# /usr/local/bin/conver cannot find error on imagemagic for movie.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagemagick, imagick

I want use moviepy so, I checking example snippets from official moviepy web site.
I installed all requirements and When I try to run moviepy on jupyter notebook, I get this error:

Code :
txt_clip = TextClip("My Holidays 2013",fontsize=70,color='white')

Error :

```
OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/convert'.

This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect
```

My os : M1 BigSur 11.2.3  - MacOS

Also I checked

```
ls /opt/homebrew/opt
ls /usr/local/Cellar
ls -l /usr/local/opt/
```

But I cannot find anything about "convert"

Btw I can user imagemagic convert from terminal like that:

> magick convert

output is like that:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.11-7 Q16 arm 2021-04-12 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp xml zlib
Usage: convert [options ...] file [ [options ...] file ...] [options ...] file

Image Settings:
  -adjoin              join images into a single multi-image file
  -affine matrix       affine transform matrix
  -alpha option        activate, deactivate, reset, or set the alpha channel
  -antialias           remove pixel-aliasing
```

How can solve this? Any tip or solution?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error.

I checked my PATH

> echo $PATH

After that, I checked path folders and I find 'convert' from /opt/homebrew/bin/convert

After that I copied this file to /usr/local/bin/

So,

> sudo cp /opt/homebrew/bin/convert /usr/local/bin/

solved my issue.